# Changing SharePoint Online Logo

Tags: sharepoint-online

## What I have

- SharePoint Online (Plan 2 as part of an E3 License)

## What I don't have

- Site Collection Permissions

Please note that I am **Not** an Administrator.

### What I need

An OOB way to change the logo for an individual site.

### What I've tried

I've attempted to replace the **siteIcon**.jpg that's located in the Site Assets library. This did not work.

I've tried making the change in the O365 group but it seems that I can only delete the icon that's there. I can't upload or drag and drop a new image to be used for the site logo.

Edit: As I'm using Microsoft Teams with this as well, I was able to change the Team/Group logo via the Microsoft Teams interface, but it did not propagate over to the SharePoint site associated with the group.

#### Solution

The solution was to replace the `__siteIcon__.jpg` with the desired image. To actually see the change, I had to clear the browser cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it should work is to update the photo in the group settings, which should then propagate automatically to the Group's SharePoint site. Note, this automatic propagation takes time, and may take 24 hours, though I've seen at least one person reporting that it took a couple days. But the image is also cached by your browser, so make sure you clear your browser cache. (If you updated the siteicon file, clear your browser cache and refresh the page. That should take effect immediately).

Note: there was a [thread](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365-Groups/Group-SP-Site-Group-image-logo-Not-Updating/td-p/40478) on the techcommunity site a while back about a bug with this feature. The bug should be fixed on any recently created site, but perhaps not with an older group site

Comment: Hot dang. Browser Cache was the issue. I thought it was weird that the image wasn't changing. Marking as the solution and editing my response to reflect the correct answer...